# Melt a Pandas Dataframe with multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-melt

I wanted to know if there's a way to melt a DataFrame with multiple column names.

I have this Pandas Data Frame:

```
Edad       2000    2001    2002    2003  ...   2017    2018    2019    2020
                                         ...                               
[15-25]  126675  158246  171958  188389  ...  78707   70246   65661   52209
(25-35]   65823   85059   92841   95394  ...  88479  157492  149862  122067
(35-45]   37474   48605   54593   56279  ...  65870   65798   64587   51502
(45-55]   20624   22067   25860   27601  ...  39476   40725   40566   33979
(55-65]   30240    9047   10500   10972  ...  20135   21095   21173   17242
```

And would like to have something like this:

```
Edad    Year  Value
[15-25] 2000  126675
[15-25] 2001  158246
[15-25] 2002  171958
[15-25] 2003  188389
```

I've used Melt before but I always address a value column, this time I have my values as cells and I'm having a very hard time figuring out how to address them.

Comment: Please share an example part of your dataframe large enough for us to reproduce the problem. NOT an image. The output of `df.head()` or `df.head().to_dict()` is often enough.

Comment: dont use an image. Post your original df table (just like your desired result).

Comment: have you tried `pd.melt` ?

Comment: Thanks to both, already corrected it.

Comment: I just tried @Umar.H's suggestion and it worked. Soryy. Hadn't thought about using it without arguments. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use melt with groupby and sort like this:

```
df.melt(id_vars='Edad', var_name='Year').groupby(['Edad','Year']).agg({'value':'first'}).reset_index().sort_values(by=['Edad','Year'], ascending=[False,True])
```

Desired results:

```
    Edad    Year    value
32  [15-25] 2000    126675
33  [15-25] 2001    158246
34  [15-25] 2002    171958
35  [15-25] 2003    188389
36  [15-25] 2017    78707
37  [15-25] 2018    70246
38  [15-25] 2019    65661
39  [15-25] 2020    52209
24  (55-65] 2000    30240
25  (55-65] 2001    9047
26  (55-65] 2002    10500
27  (55-65] 2003    10972
28  (55-65] 2017    20135
29  (55-65] 2018    21095
30  (55-65] 2019    21173
31  (55-65] 2020    17242
16  (45-55] 2000    20624
17  (45-55] 2001    22067
18  (45-55] 2002    25860
19  (45-55] 2003    27601
20  (45-55] 2017    39476
21  (45-55] 2018    40725
22  (45-55] 2019    40566
23  (45-55] 2020    33979
8   (35-45] 2000    37474
9   (35-45] 2001    48605
10  (35-45] 2002    54593
11  (35-45] 2003    56279
12  (35-45] 2017    65870
13  (35-45] 2018    65798
14  (35-45] 2019    64587
15  (35-45] 2020    51502
0   (25-35] 2000    65823
1   (25-35] 2001    85059
2   (25-35] 2002    92841
3   (25-35] 2003    95394
4   (25-35] 2017    88479
5   (25-35] 2018    157492
6   (25-35] 2019    149862
7   (25-35] 2020    122067
```